# Drag , Pinch and zoom images in UIView

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I am adding multiple `UIImageView` to a `UIView` to perform operations such as drag,pinch and zoom images.I have added gesture recogniser  to all the `UIImageViews`.Since i'm adding multiple images(UIImageViews) it has brought down the performance of my app.Does any one have  a better solution to perform this? Thanks

Comment: I don't see why adding multiple Gesture Recognisers should necessarily reduce performance. In my experience it doesn't, although I can very well be wrong on that. Can you post some code? You could alternatively get rid of the gesture recognizers and handle the touches yourself, but I doubt that you will get a big performance boost.

Comment: Performance gets reduced since i am adding multiple image views to the `UIView`.Is it possible to achieve the same functionality with out adding multiple UIImageViews to the view @JavierQuevedo-Fernández

Comment: Well, you could render the images to a single layer, but I am not sure if that would get you were you want to go. Could you post some more information on what you are trying to build, or the current way of doing so? Otherwise it is a bit difficult.

Answer (score 3):

The adding of many images should not generally, cause enough of a problem that your app would slow down. For example, to illustrate the point with an absurd example, I added 250 (!) image views each with three gestures, and it works fine on an iPad 3, including the animating of the images into their final resting place/size/rotation.

Two observations:

1. Are you doing anything computationally intensive with your image views? For example:

   - Simply adding shadows with Quartz 2D has a huge performance impact because it's actually quite computationally expensive. In the unlikely even that you're using layer shadows, you can try using `shouldRasterize`, which can mitigate the problem, but not solve it. There are other (kludgy) techniques for doing computationally efficient shadows if that's the problem.
   - Another surprising computationally intensive process is if your images are (for example) PNGs with transparency settings or if you have reduced the `alpha`/`opacity` for your views.
   - What is the resolution/size of the images being loaded? If the images are very large, the image view will render them according to the `contentMode`, but it can be very slow if you're taking large images and scaling them down. You should use screen resolution images if possible.

   These are just a few examples of things that seem so innocuous, but are really quite computationally expensive. If you're doing any Quartz embellishments on your image views, I'd suggest temporarily paring them back and see if you see any changes.
2. In terms of diagnosing the performance problems yourself, I'd suggest watching the following two WWDC videos:

   - [WWDC 2012 - #211 - Building Concurrent User Interfaces on iOS](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=211) includes a fairly pragmatic demonstration of Instruments to identify the source of performance problems. This video is clearly focused on one particular solution (the moving of computationally expensive processes into the background and implementing a concurrent UI), which may or may not apply in this case, but I like the Instruments demonstration.
   - [WWDC 2012 - #235 - iOS App Performance: Responsiveness](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2012/?id=235) is a more focused discussion on how one measures responsiveness in apps and techniques to address problems. I don't find the instruments tutorial to be quite as good as the prior video, but it does go into more detail.

Hopefully this can get you going. If you are still stumped, you should share some relevant code regarding how the views are being added/configured and what the gestures are doing. Perhaps you can also clarify the nature of the performance problem (e.g. is it in the initial rendition, is it a low frame rate while the gestures take place, etc.).